# POS specifier in Fortran read - 4 or 8 byte integer

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I read a binary file and want to specify the position in read statement:

```
READ(IOUNIT,IOSTAT=IOSTAT, POS=POSITION)
```

What I'm wondering is the type of `POSITION`. All examples I was was able to find had `POSITION` declared as a 4 byte integer. Is it possible to have it an 8 byte integer?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You should show more code, please confirm, are you using ˋaccess="stream"ˋ?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Fortran standard (Fortran 2018, R1213, 12.6.2.1; similar back to Fortran 2003) , the `POS=` specifier to the `read` statement must be a scalar integer expression.  There is no specific restriction on the kind of that integer.

If your Fortran processor supports 8-byte integers then such an integer can be used in the specifier where that specifier is supported (in particular, under stream access, hence Fortran 2003 being mentioned earlier).